# How do I use vite with the "new" .net 7 web assembly project

Tags: javascript, .net, vite, webassembly, .net-7.0

I am building an client-side application (using html/javascript) and would like to use a web assembly in it, compiled with .net 7.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/dotnet-interop

https://www.meziantou.net/using-dotnet-code-from-javascript-using-webassembly.htm

The application is NOT using blazor, it is a normal React [vite](https://vitejs.dev/)-based application. So from the dotent, I get this dotnet.js file and a bunch of other files (the AppBundle folder), and now I would like to use that from some React component in my Vite application. So how do I do that?

If I try to go directly like this:

```js
import { dotnet } = from '../../wasm/bin/Release/net7.0/browser-wasm/AppBundle/dotnet.js';

// then use use dotent
```

Then it even works in debug, but when bundling, vite cries about dynamic imports, and cannot pack the AppBundle properly, leaving the .dlls and other stuff behind. Also, `dotent.js` does not like being renamed to something like `dotnet.123ak.js`, and just breaks. Also, vite renames `dotnet.wasm` to `dotnet.123ak.wasm`, maybe this is what the dotnet part does not like.

Anyway. It would be enough to have sort of a "virtual" (unprocessed) import which I can somehow specify to resolve to the "dotent.js" file forcefully to some fixed path (external). How can I achieve this with vite? I.e. basically, I want

- my project to compile, i.e not give errors on compilation.
- the output file (say, page.tsx => page.js) to refer to some specific fixed path, like '/AppBundle/dotnet.js'. As an example:

If I import like this:

```js
import { dotnet } from 'some-file'
```

Then on build I do not get any errors, and after build I get the `some-file` replaced with `/MyAppBundle/dotnet.js` (a fixed value in config)

How can I achive this (for example, with webpack, there is "resolve" option in config, maybe there is something similar to help in vite?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. You can use `await import(...)` to make it work. Have written a post regarding this:

https://medium.com/@nbelyh/using-net-as-a-webassembly-from-javascript-react-16fd9373c411

usage

```
  const { dotnet, loading } = 
     useDotNet('/path/to/your/AppBundle/dotnet.js')
```

definition

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

export const useDotNet = (url: string) => {

  const dotnetUrl = useRef('');
  const [dotnet, setDotNet] = useState<any>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const load = async (currentUrl: string): Promise<any> => {

    const module = await import(/* @vite-ignore */ currentUrl);

    const { getAssemblyExports, getConfig } = await module
      .dotnet
      .withDiagnosticTracing(false)
      .create();

    const config = getConfig();
    const exports = await getAssemblyExports(config.mainAssemblyName);
    return exports;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (dotnetUrl.current !== url) { // safeguard to prevent double-loading
      setLoading(true);
      dotnetUrl.current = url;
      load(url)
        .then(exports => setDotNet(exports))
        .finally(() => setLoading(false))
    }
  }, [url]);
  return { dotnet, loading };
}
```

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to do something like this without copying the AppBundle folder into the public folder